# How to convert keras sequential API to functional API

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, image-recognition

I am new to deep learning, and am trying to convert this sequential API into a functional API to run on the CIFAR 10 dataset. Below is the sequential API:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
```

And here is my attempt at converting this into the functional API:

```
model_input = Input(shape=input_shape)

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='valid')(model_input)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3))(x)

x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Activation(activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(model_input, x, name='nin_cnn')

x = layers.Flatten()
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')
x = layers.Dense(10)
```

Here is the compile and train code:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, 
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

The original sequential API gets an accuracy of 0.7175999879837036, while the functional API gets an accuracy of 0.0502999983727932. Not sure where I have gone wrong when re-writing the code, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two models are not the same. The second and third convolutional layers are having 64 units and 32 units respectively for sequential and functional model in your sample code. And you did not include fully-connected layer in your functional model (you created those layer only after you constructed the model).

If you doubt in the future, you can try to do

```
model.summary()
```

and compare to see if the models are the same.

Answer (score 0):

In addition what @adrtam mentioned, I want to add few more as the user is beginner.

There are couple of important difference between Sequential and Functional models. Functional and Sequential are almost similar except,

[image]

So Sequential is single-input and single-output, and layers can be added/stacked layer by layer. Functional is more flexibility for customization. So, in a way we can say Sequential is subset of Functional Model.

Coming to your case,
Here is a Sequential model

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models
input_shape=(32, 32, 3)
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
```

Here is Functional Model.

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras import layers
model_input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='valid')(model_input)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(10)(x)

model2 = Model(model_input, x, name='nin_cnn')
```

Comment: After using this functional model, the program still gets an accuracy of around 10%. I'm not sure where it's going wrong. I could post the entire code if you wanted to have a look at it? Cheers.